# When does weak normalization imply strong normalization?

Tags: lambda-calculus, normalization

Is there a possibility to get strong normalization for some kind of $\lambda$-calculus out of weak normalization with some other assumptions?

For example:
The term $(\lambda_y z)((\lambda_x xx)(\lambda_x xx))$ is weakly normalizable and even confluent but not strongly normalizable. However, the subterm $(\lambda_x xx)(\lambda_x xx)$ is not even weakly normalizable. Hence, I was wondering if confluence and weak normalization for all subterms is sufficient for strong normalization.

This is just an idea. Please, feel free to post every sufficient condition for strong normalization which involves weak normalization.

Comment: It's not; $Y\ K$ is your counter-example. (I've had this thought before).